Расстановка знаков препинания в

То ли потому что Чехов писал по-русски то ли потому что русский для
тебя родной язык


ПРавильно:
То ли потому, что Чехов писал по-русски, то ли потому, что русский для тебя родной язык.
Пояснение
При наличии сочинительных союзов составные подчинительные союзы расчленяются, а сочинительные союзы относятся к местоименной части союза.
Розенталь, пункт 3(4):
Река приняла особенный вид потому, что вода видна сквозь голые сучья, а еще более потому, что пропал от холода водяной цвет (Акс.); Нехлюдов заехал к тётушкам потому, что имение их было по дороге к прошедшему вперёд его полку, и потому, что они его очень об этом просили (Л. Т.);
Розенталь, пункт 4:
При повторяющихся сочинительных союзах между соподчиненными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения ставится запятая: Находясь в госпитале, он вспоминал, как фашисты напали на них внезапно, и как они оказались в окружении, и как отряду всё же удалось пробиться к своим (Газ).
